# Restrict Users to View Reports in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to restrict the users to view reports in SSRS 2008.i.e; I want the user to view only 2 reports out of 20.I tried creating a new user with appropriate role and gave the user only the permission to view the two reports. But I couldn’t achieve what I needed. The User was able to view all the reports.Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate folders with different permissions and linked reports.

Permissions come from the container (folder) and it's bad practice to permission individually